# tiff2pdf failed to convert 'example' multipage tiff, although working with 'real life' samples

Tags: libtiff

I need to convert incoming TIFFs to PDFs in scripting, so I've tested `tiff2pdf`. I have actual (4.0.6) version of LIBTIFF, installed with `apt`. It did well with some samples produced by scanner, but it failed with examples from [this page](http://www.nightprogrammer.org/development/multipage-tiff-example-download-test-image-file/).

The PDF was generated, but the pages are empty when viewed with `ImageMagic` or `Print Preview` under Ubuntu, on `Acrobat` (in Windows) it shows erros that the PDF is invalid.

Is there a bug in current LIBTIFF considering multipage tiffs? Unfortunately the ['Official' bugzilla](http://bugzilla.remotesensing.org/enter_bug.cgi) is down, and I've found no reference where is the actual version... Or those examples are somehow 'non-realistic' and I should expect no scanner to produce them?

Answer (score 1):

Use -n as flag, it worked for me with the same file from your example, see https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tiff2pdf/